# Parsing XML Attributes by name with PHP5

Tags: php, xml

When trying to parse an XML document in PHP, nothing is returned.

The XML document im trying to use:

http://cdn.content.easports.com/media2011/fifa11zoneplayer/25068538/632A0001_10_ZONE_PLAYER_iUa.xml

The code I have tried:

```
$player = simplexml_load_file('http://cdn.content.easports.com/media2011/fifa11zoneplayer/25068538/632A0001_10_ZONE_PLAYER_iUa.xml');
foreach ($player->PlayerName as $playerInfo) {
     echo $playerInfo['firstName'];
}
```

I have also tried:

```
$player = simplexml_load_file('http://cdn.content.easports.com/media2011/fifa11zoneplayer/25068538/632A0001_10_ZONE_PLAYER_iUa.xml');
echo "Name: " . $player->PlayerName[0]['firstName'];
```

What do I need to change for the attributes to show?

Comment: It should be `$xml->Player->PlayerName->firstName]`, since the xml goes CreationZone->Player->PlayerName.

Comment: `PlayerName` is not in the root. It's under the `Player` element. Have you tried `->Player->PlayerName[0]`?

Comment: I tried $player->Player->PlayerName[0]->firstName; and $player->Player[0]->PlayerName[0]->firstName;  still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to `print_r` the whole data youself and finally find what you need:

```
var_dump($player->Player->PlayerName->Attrib['value']->__toString())
//⇒ string(7) "Daniele"
```

Answer (score 1):

To list all "values" (firstname, lastname,...) you need list all children and their attributes:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://cdn.content.easports.com/media2011/fifa11zoneplayer/25068538/632A0001_10_ZONE_PLAYER_iUa.xml');

 foreach ($xml as $player) {
    foreach ($player->PlayerName->children() as $attrib) {
        echo $attrib['name'] . ': ' . $attrib['value'] . PHP_EOL; 
    }

 }
```

Output:

```
firstName: Daniele
lastName: Viola
commonName: Viola D.
commentaryName:
```

Answer (score -1):

This does not work, since you are trying to access an attribute and not a node value.

You might also run into problems, because the xml is not "valid" for simple xml. See my blogpost about the issues with parsing xml with php here http://dracoblue.net/dev/gotchas-when-parsing-xml-html-with-php/

If you use my Craur ( https://github.com/DracoBlue/Craur ) library instead, it will look like this:

```
$xml_string = file_get_contents('http://cdn.content.easports.com/media2011/fifa11zoneplayer/25068538/632A0001_10_ZONE_PLAYER_iUa.xml');
$craur = Craur::createFromXml($xml_string);
echo $craur->get('Player.PlayerName.Attrib@value'); // works since the first attrib entry is the name
```

If you want to be sure about the attribute (or select another one) use:

```
$xml_string = file_get_contents('http://cdn.content.easports.com/media2011/fifa11zoneplayer/25068538/632A0001_10_ZONE_PLAYER_iUa.xml');
$craur = Craur::createFromXml($xml_string);
foreach ($craur->get('Player.PlayerName.Attrib[]') as $attribute)
{
    if ($attribute->get('@name') == 'firstName')
    {
        echo $attribute->get('@value');
    }
}
```